# How to schedule a task for non admin users?

Tags: c#, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

We are currently using [`TaskService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/taskservice) to schedule a task.  We use the default folder:

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = new TaskScheduler();
scheduler.Connect();
ITaskFolder rootFolder = scheduler.GetFolder("");
```

which turns out to be:

`C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`

This works great for admin users, but now I'm trying to schedule a task for non-admin users.  Now the above code throws a `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

I've tried specifying a user specific file paths:

```
"\\Users\\some_user"  // FileNotFoundException:  The system cannot find the file specified
"C:\\Users\\some_user"  // FileNotFoundException:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how `scheduler.GetFolder("")` was throwing an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, it seems to work fine now.

What I ended up doing was something like:

```
    TaskScheduler scheduler = new TaskScheduler();
    scheduler.Connect();
    ITaskFolder rootFolder = scheduler.GetFolder(string.Empty);
    ITaskFolder userSpecificFolder = rootFolder.CreateFolder(scheduler.ConnectedUser);  // Will throw if folder already exists
    // Now can add tasks to userSpecificFolder
```